# only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars using int function

Tags: python

I currently got an array in python which is an element of a dictionary and, in python console, looks like this:

```
TUMEC['spans'][0]
array([0. , 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.])
```

I want to pass the whole array to a function but this has to go through some simple math operation like:

```
int(TUMEC['spans'][0]*100)
```

but I got the error message saying:
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

So, I tried to `import numpy` and type:

```
int(TUMEC['spans'][0]*100)
```

but I still have the same issue.

Does anybody know how I can bypass this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SE, mate. You are supposed to accept the answer that solved your solution in the best way. You can read more about the website [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/)

Answer (score 1):

you can try converting to list and then comprehension :

```
[int(a*100) for a in list(TUMEC['spans'][0])]
```

Comment: This is a good approach as long as OP doesn't mind the result being a list and not an array.

Comment: can always convert back to array

Comment: yeah, of course.  I'm not questioning your understanding, just not sure about the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing here I think would be to use `map`, which is believe is even faster:

```
print map(lambda x: int(x*100), TUMEC['spans'][0])
```

but if `TUMEC['spans'][0]`is already a `numpy.array` then the following should work and should be the preferred way, since it is more readable, simpler and faster (can anybody confirm the fast part?).

```
print map(int, TUMEC['spans'][0]*100)
```

Of course, in both cases the result is a list, but you can easily fix that with `np.array`.